# Loss of access to the database after restarting vm

Tags: postgresql, mod-rewrite

I have this database in a VM, could restart the VM and it could access correctly

But now if I restart the VM when trying to access the DB by `pgAdmin III` I get the message below

> **Server doesn't listen**
>
> The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports
>
> **could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?**
>
> If you encounter this message, please check if the server you're
>   trying to contact is actually running PostgreSQL on the given port.
>   Test if you have network connectivity from your client to the server
>   host using ping or equivalent tools. Is your network / VPN / SSH
>   tunnel / firewall configured correctly?
>
> For security reasons, PostgreSQL does **not** listen on all available
>   IP addresses on the server machine initially. In order to access the
>   server over the network, you need to enable listening on the address
>   first.  For PostgreSQL servers starting with version 8.0, this is
>   controlled using the "listen_addresses" parameter in the
>   postgresql.conf file. Here, you can enter a list of IP addresses the
>   server should listen on, or simply use '*' to listen on all available
>   IP addresses. For earlier servers (Version 7.3 or 7.4), you'll need to
>   set the "tcpip_socket" parameter to 'true'.
>
> You can use the postgresql.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III
>   to edit the postgresql.conf configuration file. After changing this
>   file, you need to restart the server process to make the setting
>   effective.
>
> If you double-checked your configuration but still get this error
>   message, it's still unlikely that you encounter a fatal PostgreSQL
>   misbehaviour. You probably have some low level network connectivity
>   problems (e.g. firewall configuration). Please check this thoroughly
>   before reporting a bug to the PostgreSQL community.

I did some testing through VM snapshots and noticed that the behavior occurs after the command

**`sudo a2enmod rewrite`**

But I did not find anything that could indicate some link or how to solve, since I need to run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`postgresql.conf` connection settings:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)
```

I already tried to restart the postgres service, and it did not work

Comment: I think this would be much easier to answer if we knew what "sudo a2enmod rewrite" does :^)

Comment: That's just <apache2><enable><module> - shouldn't have had any effect on pg. Question to the original poster - is pgAdmin running *inside* the vm, because you are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It activates mod_rewrite

Comment: @RichardHuxton yes, running inside, but you gave me an idea and I went to try external access, and not only can I not access as well I can not access the VM through ssh, which was possible before

Comment: from the conf pg is listing on all interfaces including localhost. can you connect to 127.0.0.1:5432, try telnet 127.0.0.1 5432 also try ping localhost to see that it is mapped to 127.0.0.1 and not 127.0.1.1

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo netstat -plnt` and `ps aux | grep postgres`

Comment: You can use PGadmin to connect to a remote DB but 127.0.0.1 is localhost isn't it, would that be the same as your VM? Is pg running and netstat which port and IP it is listening on. You can even use psql to specify host and port if you wish

Answer (score 1):

This is part of my general procedure for debugging access to any database.

> **Basic tests**

*Intended to determine whether or not the services are running properly.*

Check if PostgreSQL is running:

```
pgrep -fl postgres
service postgresql status
```

(If status is available in your Linux then you should see something like this):

```
mortiz@florida:~/.mozilla/firefox/hlmpduzp.default$ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2018-06-11 14:05:04 -03; 3s ago
  Process: 17522 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17522 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 11 14:05:04 florida systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jun 11 14:05:04 florida systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

If the service is running, check the basic connectivity to the port:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5432
```

If you aren't able to connect try with localhost or the ip address (not the loopback):

```
telnet localhost 5432
telnet <your_ip_address> 5432
```

- If the service isn't running try restoring a postgresql.conf backup.
- If the service is running but you aren't able to connect to the port,
  it could be a configuration problem, try restoring the configuration
  from a backup.

If you were able to connect to the port using telnet, then the service is up and the port is open, anyway there could be configuration problems with the instance or your client.

If telnet didn't work with 127.0.0.1 but it did with localhost or -(your_ip_address / not loopback) then change that in your client settings.

If the service is running, check the basic connectivity to the port:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5432
```

If you aren't able to connect try with localhost or the ip address (not the loopback):

```
telnet localhost 5432
telnet <your_ip_address> 5432
```

- If the service isn't running try restoring a postgresql.conf backup.
- If the service is running but you aren't able to connect to the port,
  it could be a configuration problem, try restoring the configuration
  from a backup.

If you were able to connect to the port using telnet, then the service is up and the port is open, anyway there could be configuration problems with the instance or your client.

If the telnet didn't work with 127.0.0.1 but it did with localhost or  then change that in your client settings.

> **Testing functionality**

*To check the expected behavior of the service. In Linux some services start even with errors and produce undesired behaviors.*

Now it's time to see if the service is working properly, we'll use the CLI. Run this command:

```
psql -h localhost --username=postgres --list
```

And you should see the list of databases:

```
mortiz@florida:~/.mozilla/firefox/hlmpduzp.default$ psql -h localhost --username=postgres --list
Password for user postgres: 
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

If this works then your problem may be in the client **pgAdmin**. Try installing another client or version and try connecting to the database.

> **Reviewing the configuration of the server**
>   * Maybe someone changed the method of accessing the database.

Be careful, backup your file first. Check the **PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File** hosts allowed to connect / methods and users -> /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]

# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
# "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
# "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
# it sends encrypted passwords.
```

Tell me your results of each test if any problem.